# Azure AD User Sync with AD DS

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-active-directory

I am trying to configure my Azure AD to sync my On Premises AD DS in such way that if any user is added in Microsoft Azure AD it should automatically register in my On Premises AD.

I have created Azure AD and configure same domain name and connected it using Azure AD connect. Azure Management portal is showing all groups and users which was in my on-premises AD but when I am adding user in Azure AD it is not reflecting in Local AD.

Is there any possibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The engine was designed to provide one-way synchronization: from on-premise to Azure AD

Comment: That is 100% correct. Azure AD Connect is by design a one way synchronization engine. The whole idea of having Azure AD connect in place is to have the source of authority for all your objects on the local AD.